# Date without the time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm working with SQL Server 2005.

I have a column called purchase_time of type datetime. How do I select this column with the time part - just the date.

Thanks,

Barry

**EDIT:** 
Would it be safe to get the datetime and split it via Python on the first space, or is this format locale dependant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In versions < 2008 (which, based on other comments to some of the answers, I believe you are running), the most efficient way is to keep it as a datetime type and use date math to avoid string conversions.

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '20000101', purchase_time), '20000101') 
  FROM dbo.table;
```

**EDIT**

If you want the date only for display purposes, not for calculations or grouping, that is probably best handled at the client. You can do it in SQL simply by saying:

```
SELECT dt = CONVERT(CHAR(10), purchase_time, 120)
  FROM dbo.table;
```

Comment: Thanks! This gives me: 2012-02-22 00:00:00.000 but I don't want the 00:00:00.000 part.

Comment: @Baz please see update. Just make sure you keep calculation and presentation as separate concepts. It's not always best or most efficient to have SQL Server to the dirty work of "cleaning up" the data for display.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. If I do this on the client side with Python, can I presume that I will have the date part if I split on the first found space and take the first half of the result? Or can this differ from country to country, etc?

Comment: This can differ based on regional settings. If you want to be sure, you can do it in SQL. I'm sorry but I'm unfamiliar with Python, I suspect though that there are ways to format date/time values there like there are in C#, VB etc, irrespective of regional settings.

Comment: @AaronBertrand If this is a formatting issue, why not just use `SELECT dt = CONVERT(CHAR(10), purchase_time, 120) FROM dbo.table;` ?

Comment: Yes @w0lf, that's true, and actually it's what I meant to put, I just wrapped my earlier code in the outer convert. From this angle we call that laziness. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2008 you can use the newly added `date` type:

```
select convert(date, purchase_time) from TableName
```

**Update:**

In versions prior to SQL 2008, I used the following solution for this problem:

```
select convert(datetime, convert(int, convert(float, purchase_time)))
from TableName
```

Comment: This is going to be much more efficient than using convert to char/varchar to trim the time (you can test this; I have). And it negates implicit conversion (or another wrapping convert) if you need to perform date math or other comparisons on the result.

Comment: Type date is not a defined system type.

Comment: @Baz I'm sure it's available in SQL 2008; I just tested it

Comment: @Baz then I suspect you may be using Management Studio for SQL Server 2008, but connecting to a SQL Server 2005 or lower server. What does `SELECT @@VERSION` say?

Comment: @Baz Can you please check your version?

Comment: @Baz what do you say about this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx?

Comment: @Baz I've added a possible solution for SQL 2005.