# Selecting all rows that fall between midnight and a given date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In SQL Server 2008, I have a stored procedure that takes an input date. I'd like to select all rows that start at midnight on that date to 11:59pm.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
@InputDate DATETIME
AS
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE DateField >= @InputDate
```

So I want to be able to call this proc similar to like so:

```
EXEC MyProc @InputDate=CONVERT(DATETIME, '3/5/2013')
```

And it should return all rows with a date between **'3/5/2013 0:0:0'** AND **'3/5/2013 11:59:59'**. The input date should ignore the time component and just look at the date and append its own time component (at least I'm thinking it should)

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date without the time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400843/date-without-the-time), based on your comment that "the input date should ignore the time component"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DATE` data type which is accurate to one day.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
@InputDate DATE
AS
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CAST(DateField AS DATE) = @InputDate

EXEC MyProc @InputDate='2013-03-05'
```

Have a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41faf/1)

Comment: You'd want to do = @InputDate, rather than >=, yes, since just interested in that day?